Current rating of a multicore wire
Regrading this 18 AWG wire, under specifications there is this table given:

I want to use this wire to power a module which requires 12VDC and max 5A. In the specs there's nothing about max current.
But cannot conclude what is the max amperage of this wire?

The maximum current that a wire can handle depends on the environment, acceptable voltage drop, insulation temperature rating and other things.
A single wire in open air can handle a higher current than the same wire in a bundle, as it will be cooled by the surrounding air, rather than be heated by surrounding wires.
The current throught the wire's resistance will cause a voltage drop - how much drop is acceptable will depend on the load's requirements.
There are also Electrical Code requirements for wire size and insulation requirements for various enviromnental situations.

I sée. In my case A power supply rated 12VDC/10A will supply power to a module which requires 12V and 5A maximum. The wire will be connecting the powers supply to ythis module. And it will be less than 10cm. The module doesn't specify anything about voltage drop unfortunately.

For that application, #18 wire should be fine.
